# Error in two-way WCF-Port without using Orchestration

Tags: biztalk

I want to pass the response from WCF to BizTalk .

My Itinerary is

OnRamp(One way Receive Port ) ->Message Transform(Mapping) ->UDDI Resolver ->Off Ramp(Two WaySend Port)

Am calling WCF and getting the response ,after that am getting below error

> A response message sent to adapter "WCF-BasicHttp" on Receive Location: "DynamicResolutionTwoWay" with URI:"http://pc133056.cts.com/TwoWayAllocation/CRMDetailService.svc" is suspended.
>    Error details: There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: "Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines.ItinerarySelectSendReceive, Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "ESB Itinerary Selector" Send Port: "DynamicResolutionTwoWay" URI: "http://pc133056.cts.com/TwoWayAllocation/CRMDetailService.svc" Reason: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: config

Here am getting response from WCF, after that it passing the data again and getting the above error

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: The issue is the the response(receive) pipeline according to the error.  What components are in that pipeline and are they configured?

Answer (score 0):

With an itinerary select pipeline, don't you need to configure the itinerary selector component of it so it can determine which itinerary to select?